# listen() doesn't return?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get started with Node, and have hit a hump.  When I try
to run the below (same example I've seen everywhere) the "starting..."
line executes, as well as "created.", but it seems like the script gets stuck on the next line, and never prints "started." (and the server doesn't work, tried via a
browser, telnet, curl, etc).  Any advice on how to debug?

```
var http = require("http");

function onRequest(request, response) {
  console.log("Request received.");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}

console.log("starting...");
var s = http.createServer(onRequest);
console.log("created.");
s.listen(8888);
console.log("started.");
```

Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1 (squeeze), 2.6.39-x86_64

Compiled node.js 2011.07.19 v0.4.10 (stable) from source.

Thanks!

Comment: tested with node 0.4.8 and it works -> I saw 'started' message and i can access the server with the address 127.0.0.1:8888

Comment: thanks. odd, I can try downgrading to 0.4.8 (0.4.10 is marked as stable, and this seems like something else is fundamentally wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it looks like listening has some problems with socket access. Try to change port number, turn off the firewall or run node with root access. Maybe it should help;
In other way try it with python or smth like that;

Comment: Other servers have no problem binding to 8888.  I tried changing the port number, running as root, still nothing...

The odd thing is there's no errors printed (that I can see).  Tried the --debug option, but I don't think that does what I want.

Comment: Could you to try if TCP/Unix sockets works wrong? [Socket API](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/net.html#net.Socket)

Answer (score 0):

Change the port number to 3000 AND run as root.  Ensure port 3000 is NOT being used (i.e. use netstat).  You should see the "started" message.  Otherwise, I can't really help.  I'm running Node 0.4.10 on Ubuntu and I copied/pasted your code; it runs perfectly.  If it still doesn't work, reinstall Node.